# How to use azure logic app action to download files in browser

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I originally created a logic app that would, given a JSON payload, run a stored procedure, transform the results into a CSV table and then email the CSV to a specified email account.  Unfortunately requirements changed slightly and instead of emailing the csv they want it to download directly in the browser.

I am unable to get the HTTP response action to tell the browser to download the file using the Content-Disposition header. It looks like this is pulled out of the request by design.  Is anyone aware of another action (perhaps a function?) that could be used in place of the HTTP response to get a web browser to download the file rather than returning it as text in the response body?

Comment: I would suggest you to put the CSV in a blob storage and return the sas token or sas url so users will be able to download the file from this url

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but unfortunately I cannot dictate the type of return results.  While returning a URL is a good idea, the requirement is a direct download in the browser

Comment: You can send a response redirect to this url so it will be a direct download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does indeed seem to be the case that the Response action doesn't support the Content-Disposition header for some reason. Probably the easiest workround is to proxy the request through a simple HTTP-triggered Azure Function with CORS enabled (or an API on your server) that just fetches the file from the Logic App and then returns it with the Content-Disposition header attached.

NB. Don't rely on `<a download="filename">` - most browsers that support the download attribute only respect it for same-origin requests.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I was hoping that there was a simpler path that would keep everything contained in the logic app but it appears that this won't be the case.  Since it appears I will need to create a function to handle at least part of this I will more than likely just put everything in the azure function itself to keep things concise.